# Send selected text from browser to java program

Tags: java, plugins, browser, browser-plugin

I am consuming a web-service of a social-networking system where i  can post something on their page. Now i want to create an application using which i should be able to post the selected text in a browser. So i need some details on,
   1. Is it possible to send the selected text from a browser to a java program?
   2. If so, How can i add my user defined function when am doing right click on the browser?
   3. From that click event how can i send the text to my Java program?
   4. If it is not possible through java can i implement using dot net services?

Answer (score 0):

you can use java robot
It can perform action like muose click at paticular point copy paste etc

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using context menu of IE. An html page should be linked with the context menu and in that html page we can invoke the web-service through ajax call.